# How to change the layout background color by clicking a button?

Tags: android

I have two xml layouts.

One with a Button.

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.seluhadu.colorpicker.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="136dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="123dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And one with a Relative Layout with just an id.

maintwo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.seluhadu.colorpicker.MainActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have one  MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

I want to click in the Button in the main.xml and change the background color of the Maintwo.xml layout.
I tried to call `findViewById` but it is in another xml, so it does not work because setContentView is main.xml

How do I call the id of the other xml to my main Activity?

How do make an onClick listener for the Button and get the id of maintwo.xml to change the background?

Comment: You can't reference maintwo.xml since only one Activity is active at any moment

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have two Activities, you'll need to set the button click to call startActivity to your second Activity, meanwhile passing the color data through the intent, preferably as an hexadecimal string such as `#ff00ff00` for green.

[How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

After that, you may use findViewById for the second layout and set its color

Also, see `Color.parseColor()`

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.other_layout, null);
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.your_view_id);
rl.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
```

More information about inflating layouts can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

Comment: You could also `<include>` maintwo.xml in the first layout

Comment: cricket_007 is right, you can also <include> maintwo.xml in the first layout